# inserir um item em uma lista com firebase

Tags: firebase

estou desenvolvendo um projeto com angular 4 e firebase.
meu problema é o seguinte. 
tenho uma lista de viagens quero criar uma viagem (viagem1 e inserir um cronograma nela. até ai fiz um `firebasedb.list('Viagens/cronograma')`
agora queria saber como criar outra viagem com outro cronograma sem que ele caia de novo na mesma lista ex: `viagens2/cronograma2`. 
aguem tem alguma dica de como fazer isso? Obrigado.

Comment: da mesma forma que você incluiu o primeiro não daria pra fazer o segundo?

Comment: o problema é que eu teria que criar um novo componente para cada viagem que eu for criar e não acho que essa seja a melhor forma pois limitaria a quantidade de viagens,
eu pensei em criar um select com o id da viagem e escolher para qual vai o cronograma.
assim  poderia criar varias viagens e decidir em qual por o cronograma.
porem também não sei como chamar uma $key  para inserir outra lista nela

Comment: Se puder coloque se código e indique também se está usando o Realtime Database ou Cloud Firestore (adicionando a respectiva tag)